# Why is "Umlaut" in JavaDoc @author tag printed incorrectly under Eclipse Photon?

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, eclipse-photon

My user name in eclipse has an `ü`.
If I add an autogenerated javadoc with an `@author` tag in Eclipse neon, my name is written correctly.

In eclipse photon the `ü` is changed to `Ã¼`. I can change it manually, but this makes not sense in an autogenerated content.

How can I change this?

I've changed the encoding of the workspace, but it doesn't work.

Can somebody help me here?

Comment: [1] When using auto-generation on Neon did you have to do anything for the character with an umlaut to display correctly, or did it just work without any action required from you? [2] What is your operating system?

Comment: In neo I did nothing, and it works. I'm using windows10